# HTTPS WSDL soap:address location is not correctly rewritten by web-service-proxy

Tags: web-services, proxy, mule

This problem is present in mule 1.3.2-201212121943

WSDL soap:address location is not correctly rewritten by web-service-proxy with .NET WS

```
<mule ...>
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS"  sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000"  doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <https:tls-client path="xyz\keystore.jks" storePassword="mulepassword"/>
    </https:connector>

    <pattern:web-service-proxy name="xyz-ws-proxy"  >
      <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081"/>
      <https:outbound-endpoint followRedirects="true" address="https://xyz/g2g/BPM#[header:inbound:http.request.path]" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" />
    </pattern:web-service-proxy>
</mule>
```

`http://localhost:8081/xyz.asmx?wsdl` returns wsdl with

```
<wsdl:port name="XYZEndpointSoap" binding="tns:XYZEndpointSoap">
  <soap:address location="http://xyz/g2g/BPM/xyz.asmx" />
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="XYZEndpointSoap12" binding="tns:XYZEndpointSoap12">
  <soap12:address location="http://xyzg2g/BPM/xyz.asmx" />
</wsdl:port>
```

With another jax-ws service, this configuration works - there was only one soap:address hmm.

This is .NET WS.

Thank you

PS: I have read google results and closed mule issues but nothing works for this service.

Comment: This is potentially due to the expression `#[header:inbound:http.request.path]` in  the address? Can you confirm this bug is caused by it? Also Mule 1.3.2 is 6 years old, you probably meant Mule 3.3.2?

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is NOT caused by expression. I tested also full URL in the outbound endpoint. Version I mentioned is incorrect - my mule version is 3.3.1. Mule Studio version is 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and `pattern:web-service-proxy` has no problem rewrite all the addresses of a WSDL that contains both a `soap:address` and a `soap12:address`.

The issue could actually be due to the way you get the WSDL: with the HTTP inbound endpoint bound to `http://localhost:8081` with no `path` (something I would advocate against: it's better to have a `path`), the WSDL is available at `http://localhost:8081/?wsdl`, not `http://localhost:8081/xyz.asmx?wsdl`.

Comment: Thank you @DavidDossot. I tested inbound address with path too. It does NOT work. `<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/hello"/>`. Before I posted my problem, I created HTTPS WS on localhost myself and with this proxy it worked nicely. I don't know what is different with this WS - I am thinking about some HTTP header problems or compression on the server side.